# The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null

Tags: flutter, dart

To isolate the issue,  I created a new code, a new program, and a new machine.
Same results, it just doesn't want to print any value that has  is after  "quotes and has "anythingPrice"

Again I can give you a temp key and you can fully run the code. on your side.

Please let me know.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
//import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/main.dart' as app;
//import 'package:flutter_web_ui/ui.dart' as ui;


Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
 // await client.get('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=CNPF,ICOL,PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,IPFF,SMB,YDIV,YYY,PEY,IEI,TLH,DIA,BSJF,MONY&types=quote,stats&token=');

  await client.get('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,IPFF,SMB,YDIV,YYY,PEY,PGF,SNLN,DVHL,AUNZ,MDIV,PHB,PFXF,FPE,TIPX,MLN,SDIV,SIPE,SEMF,EMAG,IEMF,EU,BSCM,LEMF,BSCL,BSCK,BSCJ,BSCI,DSUM,BSCF,KBWD,PCEF,BSCG,BSCH,HYEM,ITM,BKLN,PGHY,IBCE,PZT,IJNK,XMPT,THHY,QYLD,IHY,IYLD,SHYD,PRB,DVHI,GOVT,BSJJ,BSJK,RIGS,INY,IBCD,PZA,PFIG,IBCC,BSCE,PVI,MBG,CXA,FWDB,DIV,CHLC,BSJI,FLTR,PWZ,MUAH,IBDD,PICB,IBDB,BSJH,RVNU,BSJG,IBDC,XOVR,BSJE,EBND,PCY,BWX,SJNK,DES,ANGL,BAB,SST,EMCD,CBND,HYD,PLW,SCPB,FLRN,BWZ,KBWY,ELD,IBND,AOK,RWXL,ITR,DON,DGRS,JNK,TZD,EPU,PFF,HYLD,GGOV,ULST,SPHD,HFIN,DGRW,LWC,ALD,LEMB,AGND,ITIP,EMHY,QLTC,TFI,SRLN,HYLS,SHM,GNMA,CEMB,IGOV,MINC,AGZD,FTSL,SPLV,GHYG,ISTB,ENGN,CMBS,GTIP,SCHO,SMMU,QLTA,SCHZ,HSPX,TUZ,GIY,GSY,TFLO,VMBS,CWB,FLOT,STPZ,MUAC,SCHR,BABZ,HYXU,GMTB,MUNI,WIP,MUAD,QLTB,SCHP,GMMB,MUAE,IPE,NYF,BNDX,MUAF,HYMB,TIPZ,CMF,LAG,ILTB,ITE,CLY,VGSH,VGIT,LTPZ,BABS,HYHG,EMCB,DVYL,VGLT,DHS,TLO,VWOB,IGHG,GLCB,RAVI,VCSH,BSV,BND,BIV,ISHG,SDYL,VCIT,SHY,BLV,HYG,VCLT,TENZ,DTN,BIL,AUD,DLN,DTD,FTSD,CAD,STIP,CORP,HYS,HOLD,TRSY,IEF,IBDA,COBO,BOND,MINT,MBB,CSJ,AGG,SUB,EMB,CIU,GVI,MUB,GBF,TIP,AGZ,CFT,LQD,TLT,IEI,TLH,DIA,BSJF,MONY&types=stats,quote&token=');
  //https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/stock/market/batch?&types=price&symbols=aapl,fb,tsla&token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
  //https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/stock/market/batch?&types=quote&symbols=aapl,fb,tsla&token=
  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  //https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=CNPF,ICOL,PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,IPFF,SMB,YDIV,YYY,PEY,PGF,SNLN,DVHL,AUNZ,MDIV,PHB,PFXF,FPE,TIPX,MLN,SDIV,SIPE,SEMF,EMAG,IEMF,EU,BSCM,LEMF,BSCL,BSCK,BSCJ,BSCI,DSUM,BSCF,KBWD,PCEF,BSCG,BSCH,HYEM,ITM,BKLN,PGHY,IBCE,PZT,IJNK,XMPT,THHY,QYLD,IHY,IYLD,SHYD,PRB,DVHI,GOVT,BSJJ,BSJK,RIGS,INY,IBCD,PZA,PFIG,IBCC,BSCE,PVI,MBG,CXA,FWDB,DIV,CHLC,BSJI,FLTR,PWZ,MUAH,IBDD,PICB,IBDB,BSJH,RVNU,BSJG,IBDC,XOVR,BSJE,EBND,PCY,BWX,SJNK,DES,ANGL,BAB,SST,EMCD,CBND,HYD,PLW,SCPB,FLRN,BWZ,KBWY,ELD,IBND,AOK,RWXL,ITR,DON,DGRS,JNK,TZD,EPU,PFF,HYLD,GGOV,ULST,SPHD,HFIN,DGRW,LWC,ALD,LEMB,AGND,ITIP,EMHY,QLTC,TFI,SRLN,HYLS,SHM,GNMA,CEMB,IGOV,MINC,AGZD,FTSL,SPLV,GHYG,ISTB,ENGN,CMBS,GTIP,SCHO,SMMU,QLTA,SCHZ,HSPX,TUZ,GIY,GSY,TFLO,VMBS,CWB,FLOT,STPZ,MUAC,SCHR,BABZ,HYXU,GMTB,MUNI,WIP,MUAD,QLTB,SCHP,GMMB,MUAE,IPE,NYF,BNDX,MUAF,HYMB,TIPZ,CMF,LAG,ILTB,ITE,CLY,VGSH,VGIT,LTPZ,BABS,HYHG,EMCB,DVYL,VGLT,DHS,TLO,VWOB,IGHG,GLCB,RAVI,VCSH,BSV,BND,BIV,ISHG,SDYL,VCIT,SHY,BLV,HYG,VCLT,TENZ,DTN,BIL,AUD,DLN,DTD,FTSD,CAD,STIP,CORP,HYS,HOLD,TRSY,IEF,IBDA,COBO,BOND,MINT,MBB,CSJ,AGG,SUB,EMB,CIU,GVI,MUB,GBF,TIP,AGZ,CFT,LQD,TLT,IEI,TLH,DIA,BSJF,MONY&types=quote,stats&token=
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  //final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String,dynamic>>();

  //return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();

  dynamic Obj = json.decode(responseBody);
  debugPrint(responseBody, wrapWidth: 8192);
  print(Obj.length);

  List<Photo> photoList = [];
  Obj.forEach((k, v) => photoList.add(Photo(k,v)));

  return photoList;
}

class Photo {
  String symbol;
  //String companyName;
  dynamic data;
 // dynamic iexClose;
 // dynamic quote;
  Photo(this.symbol ,this.data);


}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final appTitle = 'Monthly Paying ETFs';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),

    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {


  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(

        drawer: Drawer(
          // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
          // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
          // space to fit everything.
          child: ListView(
            // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('About'),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('This app is to provide the list of ETF s that pay monthly dividend'),

                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app
                  // ...
                  // Then close the drawer
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },


              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('for questions or feedback please contact me at  '),

                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app
                  // ...
                  // Then close the drawer
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },


              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),

        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
          backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),

      body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(

        future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),

        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


class PhotosList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos})
      : assert(photos != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _PhotosListState createState() => _PhotosListState();
}

class _PhotosListState extends State<PhotosList> {
  @override




  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return bodyData();

  }


  SingleChildScrollView bodyData() =>

    SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

      // padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
       //padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
       //  padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.001, .001, 1.0, 1.0),
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.05),


 // child: FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.contain,

  child:SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

  child:
  FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
  child: DataTable(
         // sortColumnIndex: 1,
        //  sortAscending: true,

          columns: <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(
              label: Text("Company"),
              onSort: (_, __) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.photos.sort((a, b) =>
                      a.data["quote"]["companyName"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["companyName"]));
                });
              },
            ),


            DataColumn(
              label: Text("ttmDivRate"),
              numeric: true,
              onSort:   (_,__) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.photos.sort((a, b) =>
                      a.data["quote"]["ttmDividendRate"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["ttmDividendRate"]));
                });
              },
            ),

            DataColumn(
              label: Text("Price"),
              numeric: true,
              onSort: (_, __) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data ["quote"]["latestPrice"]
                      .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["latestPrice"]));
                });
              },
            ),



          ],

          rows: widget.photos

              .map(
                (photo) =>

                DataRow(
                  cells: [



                    DataCell(
                      Text('${photo.data["stats"]["companyName"] ?? ""}'),
                    ),

                    DataCell(
                      Text('${photo.data["stats"]["ttmDividendRate"] ?? ""}'),
                   ),
//["quote"]["stats"]
                    DataCell(
                      Text('${photo.data["quote"]["stats"]["latestPrice"] ?? ""}')
                    ),

                  ],
                ),

          )

              .toList())


),
   ),

    );


}
```

The issue is that values are there and Flutter says is null when the output is in the console.

```
===================
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           17.9s
Waiting for iPhone 11 Pro Max to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57768/yyPV-GQyldg=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro Max...
flutter: {"PGX":{"stats":{"week52change":-0.025465,"week52high":15.28,"week52low":9.71,"marketcap":4595628000,"employees":null,"day200MovingAvg":14.55,"day50MovingAvg":13.39,"float":null,"avg10Volume":2336007.5,"avg30Volume":2648722.77,"ttmEPS":null,"ttmDividendRate":0.8361,"companyName":"Invesco Preferred ETF","sharesOutstanding":324550000,"maxChangePercent":-0.3042,"year5ChangePercent":-0.0367,"year2ChangePercent":-0.0167,"year1ChangePercent":-0.025465,"ytdChangePercent":-0.064111,"month6ChangePercent":-0.045822,"month3ChangePercent":-0.052209,"month1ChangePercent":0.019438,"day30ChangePercent":0.028322,"day5ChangePercent":0.015054,"nextDividendDate":"2020-05-18","dividendYield":0.059046610169491524,"nextEarningsDate":null,"exDividendDate":"2020-05-18","peRatio":null,"beta":0.5684535732534528},"quote":{"symbol":"PGX","companyName":"Invesco Preferred ETF","primaryExchange":"NYSE Arca","calculationPrice":"close","open":14.11,"openTime":1590154200191,"openSource":"official","close":14.16,"closeT<…>
flutter: 2020","latestUpdate":1590177600180,"latestVolume":4747,"iexRealtimePrice":null,"iexRealtimeSize":null,"iexLastUpdated":null,"delayedPrice":11.245,"delayedPriceTime":1590192000004,"oddLotDelayedPrice":11.193,"oddLotDelayedPriceTime":1590173727614,"extendedPrice":11.245,"extendedChange":0.005,"extendedChangePercent":0.00044,"extendedPriceTime":1590186600005,"previousClose":11.16,"previousVolume":8688,"change":0.08,"changePercent":0.00717,"volume":4747,"iexMarketPercent":null,"iexVolume":null,"avgTotalVolume":12262,"iexBidPrice":null,"iexBidSize":null,"iexAskPrice":null,"iexAskSize":null,"iexOpen":null,"iexOpenTime":null,"iexClose":11.04,"iexCloseTime":1589988569572,"marketCap":35406000,"peRatio":null,"week52High":16.6,"week52Low":8.47,"ytdChange":-0.300712,"lastTradeTime":1590177600181,"isUSMarketOpen":false}},"IPFF":{"stats":{"week52change":-0.23383400000000001,"week52high":15.71,"week52low":8.38,"marketcap":28738500,"employees":null,"day200MovingAvg":13.89,"day50MovingAvg":10.96,"float<…>
flutter: 95
flutter: {"PGX":{"stats":{"week52change":-0.025465,"week52high":15.28,"week52low":9.71,"marketcap":4595628000,"employees":null,"day200MovingAvg":14.55,"day50MovingAvg":13.39,"float":null,"avg10Volume":2336007.5,"avg30Volume":2648722.77,"ttmEPS":null,"ttmDividendRate":0.8361,"companyName":"Invesco Preferred ETF","sharesOutstanding":324550000,"maxChangePercent":-0.3042,"year5ChangePercent":-0.0367,"year2ChangePercent":-0.0167,"year1ChangePercent":-0.025465,"ytdChangePercent":-0.064111,"month6ChangePercent":-0.045822,"month3ChangePercent":-0.052209,"month1ChangePercent":0.019438,"day30ChangePercent":0.028322,"day5ChangePercent":0.015054,"nextDividendDate":"2020-05-18","dividendYield":0.059046610169491524,"nextEarningsDate":null,"exDividendDate":"2020-05-18","peRatio":null,"beta":0.5684535732534528},"**quote":{"symbol":"PGX","companyName":"Invesco Preferred ETF","primaryExchange":"NYSE Arca","calculationPrice":"close","open":14.11,"openTime":1590154200191,"openSource":"official","close":14.16,"closeT<…>
flutter: 2020","latestUpdate":1590177600180,"latestVolume":4747,"iexRealtimePrice":null,"iexRealtimeSize":null,"iexLastUpdated":null,"delayedPrice":11.245,"delayedPriceTime":1590192000004,"oddLotDelayedPrice":11.193,"oddLotDelayedPriceTime":1590173727614,"extendedPrice":11.245,"extendedChange":0.005,"extendedChangePercent":0.00044,"extendedPriceTime":1590186600005,"previousClose":11.16,"previousVolume":8688,"change":0.08,"changePercent":0.00717,"volume":4747,"iexMarketPercent":null,"iexVolume":null,"avgTotalVolume":12262,"iexBidPrice":null,"iexBidSize":null,"iexAskPrice":null,"iexAskSize":null,"iexOpen":null,"iexOpenTime":null,"iexClose":11.04,"iexCloseTime":1589988569572,"marketCap":35406000,"peRatio":null,"week52High":16.6,"week52Low":8.47,"ytdChange":-0.300712,"lastTradeTime":1590177600181,"isUSMarketOpen":false}},"IPFF":{"stats":{"week52change":-0.23383400000000001,"week52high":15.71,"week52low":8.38,"marketcap":28738500,"employees":null,"day200MovingAvg":13.89,"day50MovingAvg":10.96,"float<…>
flutter: 95**

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building photorealist(dirty, state: _PhotosListState#8eef8):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("iexClose")
```

=============
Column Price is empty. 
If I try to call  **"delayedPrice":11.552,"** or **"iexClose":11.04.** it does not print in the app. 
[image]

Comment: @chunhunghan ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building photorealist(dirty, state: _PhotosListState#8eef8): The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:

Comment: I think you are facing issues with fetching and then saving/using the data using a model. You should have a look at this answer then try to implement and get the data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708634/9236994

Comment: Yes, whatever is after ""quote":{"symbol":"PGX","companyName":"Invesco Preferred ETF","primaryExchange":"NYSE Arca","calculationPrice":"close","open":14.11,"openTime":1590154200191,"openSource":"official","close":14.16,"closeT<…> flutter:"  it doesn't pick up.  it used to work before. I don't recall any changes. I think is a Flutter problem.

Comment: if you receive an error while trying to build a model using method mentioned in above answer then most probably there's something wrong with your output's json response structure.

Comment: I agree. the question is what. I was working as it is before.

Comment: @chunhunghan hey bud want to pitch in!

Comment: hi can you share the json response in a file, or give a temp key so that one can give it a try

Comment: @vicky-salunkhe provided to your Gmail account in Github

Comment: @DevEd Please add sample json response

Comment: @Crazy-Lazy-Cat here is the key to repro the issue pk_fd71da12cae34ae9abdf3df4958302fe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the response, for some companies (or symbol) the `quote` value is `null`.

Example(IEMF, EU, etc):

```
     "IEMF": {
          "stats": {
               "symbol": "IEMF",
               "nextDividendDate": null,
               "nextEarningsDate": null,
               "exDividendDate": null,
               "peRatio": null,
               "beta": null
          },
          "quote": null
     },
     "EU": {
          "stats": {
               "symbol": "EU",
               "nextDividendDate": null,
               "nextEarningsDate": null,
               "exDividendDate": null,
               "peRatio": null,
               "beta": null
          },
          "quote": null
     },
```

**Check:**

> photo.data["quote"] != null

And there is no `stats` inside `quote`. so don't call `photo.data["quote"]["stats"]`

Instead of `Text('${photo.data["quote"]["stats"]["latestPrice"] ?? ""}')`, use `Text('${(photo.data["quote"] != null ? photo.data["quote"]["latestPrice"] : "") ?? ""}')`

**Full Code:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/main.dart' as app;
//import 'package:flutter_web_ui/ui.dart' as ui;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      // await client.get('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=CNPF,ICOL,PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,IPFF,SMB,YDIV,YYY,PEY,IEI,TLH,DIA,BSJF,MONY&types=quote,stats&token=');
      await client.get(
    'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,IPFF,SMB,YDIV,YYY,PEY,PGF,SNLN,DVHL,AUNZ,MDIV,PHB,PFXF,FPE,TIPX,MLN,SDIV,SIPE,SEMF,EMAG,IEMF,EU,BSCM,LEMF,BSCL,BSCK,BSCJ,BSCI,DSUM,BSCF,KBWD,PCEF,BSCG,BSCH,HYEM,ITM,BKLN,PGHY,IBCE,PZT,IJNK,XMPT,THHY,QYLD,IHY,IYLD,SHYD,PRB,DVHI,GOVT,BSJJ,BSJK,RIGS,INY,IBCD,PZA,PFIG,IBCC,BSCE,PVI,MBG,CXA,FWDB,DIV,CHLC,BSJI,FLTR,PWZ,MUAH,IBDD,PICB,IBDB,BSJH,RVNU,BSJG,IBDC,XOVR,BSJE,EBND,PCY,BWX,SJNK,DES,ANGL,BAB,SST,EMCD,CBND,HYD,PLW,SCPB,FLRN,BWZ,KBWY,ELD,IBND,AOK,RWXL,ITR,DON,DGRS,JNK,TZD,EPU,PFF,HYLD,GGOV,ULST,SPHD,HFIN,DGRW,LWC,ALD,LEMB,AGND,ITIP,EMHY,QLTC,TFI,SRLN,HYLS,SHM,GNMA,CEMB,IGOV,MINC,AGZD,FTSL,SPLV,GHYG,ISTB,ENGN,CMBS,GTIP,SCHO,SMMU,QLTA,SCHZ,HSPX,TUZ,GIY,GSY,TFLO,VMBS,CWB,FLOT,STPZ,MUAC,SCHR,BABZ,HYXU,GMTB,MUNI,WIP,MUAD,QLTB,SCHP,GMMB,MUAE,IPE,NYF,BNDX,MUAF,HYMB,TIPZ,CMF,LAG,ILTB,ITE,CLY,VGSH,VGIT,LTPZ,BABS,HYHG,EMCB,DVYL,VGLT,DHS,TLO,VWOB,IGHG,GLCB,RAVI,VCSH,BSV,BND,BIV,ISHG,SDYL,VCIT,SHY,BLV,HYG,VCLT,TENZ,DTN,BIL,AUD,DLN,DTD,FTSD,CAD,STIP,CORP,HYS,HOLD,TRSY,IEF,IBDA,COBO,BOND,MINT,MBB,CSJ,AGG,SUB,EMB,CIU,GVI,MUB,GBF,TIP,AGZ,CFT,LQD,TLT,IEI,TLH,DIA,BSJF,MONY&types=stats,quote&token=pk_fd71da12cae34ae9abdf3df4958302fe',
  );
  //https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/stock/market/batch?&types=price&symbols=aapl,fb,tsla&token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
  //https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/stock/market/batch?&types=quote&symbols=aapl,fb,tsla&token=
  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  //https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=CNPF,ICOL,PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,IPFF,SMB,YDIV,YYY,PEY,PGF,SNLN,DVHL,AUNZ,MDIV,PHB,PFXF,FPE,TIPX,MLN,SDIV,SIPE,SEMF,EMAG,IEMF,EU,BSCM,LEMF,BSCL,BSCK,BSCJ,BSCI,DSUM,BSCF,KBWD,PCEF,BSCG,BSCH,HYEM,ITM,BKLN,PGHY,IBCE,PZT,IJNK,XMPT,THHY,QYLD,IHY,IYLD,SHYD,PRB,DVHI,GOVT,BSJJ,BSJK,RIGS,INY,IBCD,PZA,PFIG,IBCC,BSCE,PVI,MBG,CXA,FWDB,DIV,CHLC,BSJI,FLTR,PWZ,MUAH,IBDD,PICB,IBDB,BSJH,RVNU,BSJG,IBDC,XOVR,BSJE,EBND,PCY,BWX,SJNK,DES,ANGL,BAB,SST,EMCD,CBND,HYD,PLW,SCPB,FLRN,BWZ,KBWY,ELD,IBND,AOK,RWXL,ITR,DON,DGRS,JNK,TZD,EPU,PFF,HYLD,GGOV,ULST,SPHD,HFIN,DGRW,LWC,ALD,LEMB,AGND,ITIP,EMHY,QLTC,TFI,SRLN,HYLS,SHM,GNMA,CEMB,IGOV,MINC,AGZD,FTSL,SPLV,GHYG,ISTB,ENGN,CMBS,GTIP,SCHO,SMMU,QLTA,SCHZ,HSPX,TUZ,GIY,GSY,TFLO,VMBS,CWB,FLOT,STPZ,MUAC,SCHR,BABZ,HYXU,GMTB,MUNI,WIP,MUAD,QLTB,SCHP,GMMB,MUAE,IPE,NYF,BNDX,MUAF,HYMB,TIPZ,CMF,LAG,ILTB,ITE,CLY,VGSH,VGIT,LTPZ,BABS,HYHG,EMCB,DVYL,VGLT,DHS,TLO,VWOB,IGHG,GLCB,RAVI,VCSH,BSV,BND,BIV,ISHG,SDYL,VCIT,SHY,BLV,HYG,VCLT,TENZ,DTN,BIL,AUD,DLN,DTD,FTSD,CAD,STIP,CORP,HYS,HOLD,TRSY,IEF,IBDA,COBO,BOND,MINT,MBB,CSJ,AGG,SUB,EMB,CIU,GVI,MUB,GBF,TIP,AGZ,CFT,LQD,TLT,IEI,TLH,DIA,BSJF,MONY&types=quote,stats&token=
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  //final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String,dynamic>>();

  //return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();

  dynamic obj = json.decode(responseBody);
  debugPrint(responseBody, wrapWidth: 1000);
  print(obj.length);

  List<Photo> photoList = [];
  obj.forEach((k, v) => photoList.add(Photo(k, v)));

  return photoList;
}

class Photo {
  String symbol;

  //String companyName;
  dynamic data;

  // dynamic iexClose;
  // dynamic quote;
  Photo(this.symbol, this.data);
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Monthly Paying ETFs';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('About'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'This app is to provide the list of ETF s that pay monthly dividend',
              ),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'for questions or feedback please contact me at  ',
              ),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
        future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos})
      : assert(photos != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _PhotosListState createState() => _PhotosListState();
}

class _PhotosListState extends State<PhotosList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return bodyData();
  }

  SingleChildScrollView bodyData() => SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        //padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        //  padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.001, .001, 1.0, 1.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.05),

        // child: FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.contain,

        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            child: DataTable(
              // sortColumnIndex: 1,
              //  sortAscending: true,

              columns: <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text("Company"),
                  onSort: (_, __) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["quote"]
                              ["companyName"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["companyName"]));
                    });
                  },
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text("ttmDivRate"),
                  numeric: true,
                  onSort: (_, __) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["quote"]
                              ["ttmDividendRate"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["ttmDividendRate"]));
                    });
                  },
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text("Price"),
                  numeric: true,
                  onSort: (_, __) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["quote"]
                              ["latestPrice"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["latestPrice"]));
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
              rows: widget.photos
                  .map(
                    (photo) => DataRow(
                      cells: [
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            '${photo.data["stats"]["companyName"] ?? ""}',
                          ),
                        ),

                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            '${photo.data["stats"]["ttmDividendRate"] ?? ""}',
                          ),
                        ),
//["quote"]["stats"]
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            '${(photo.data["quote"] != null ? photo.data["quote"]["latestPrice"] : "") ?? ""}',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through the token you shared and tested the code you shared.

you are calling the array in a wrong way from where the error is being raised.

I tried it and output is being shown without any error

```
  DataCell(
      Text('${photo.data["quote"]["stats"]["latestPrice"] ?? ""}')   //❌
      //REPLACE   ["quote"]["stats"]    with   ["stats"]
      Text('${photo.data["stats"]["latestPrice"] ?? ""}')   //✔️
  ),
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

WORKING CODE

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
//import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/main.dart' as app;
//import 'package:flutter_web_ui/ui.dart' as ui;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      // await client.get('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=CNPF,ICOL,PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,IPFF,SMB,YDIV,YYY,PEY,IEI,TLH,DIA,BSJF,MONY&types=quote,stats&token=');

      await client.get(
          'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,IPFF,SMB,YDIV,YYY,PEY,PGF,SNLN,DVHL,AUNZ,MDIV,PHB,PFXF,FPE,TIPX,MLN,SDIV,SIPE,SEMF,EMAG,IEMF,EU,BSCM,LEMF,BSCL,BSCK,BSCJ,BSCI,DSUM,BSCF,KBWD,PCEF,BSCG,BSCH,HYEM,ITM,BKLN,PGHY,IBCE,PZT,IJNK,XMPT,THHY,QYLD,IHY,IYLD,SHYD,PRB,DVHI,GOVT,BSJJ,BSJK,RIGS,INY,IBCD,PZA,PFIG,IBCC,BSCE,PVI,MBG,CXA,FWDB,DIV,CHLC,BSJI,FLTR,PWZ,MUAH,IBDD,PICB,IBDB,BSJH,RVNU,BSJG,IBDC,XOVR,BSJE,EBND,PCY,BWX,SJNK,DES,ANGL,BAB,SST,EMCD,CBND,HYD,PLW,SCPB,FLRN,BWZ,KBWY,ELD,IBND,AOK,RWXL,ITR,DON,DGRS,JNK,TZD,EPU,PFF,HYLD,GGOV,ULST,SPHD,HFIN,DGRW,LWC,ALD,LEMB,AGND,ITIP,EMHY,QLTC,TFI,SRLN,HYLS,SHM,GNMA,CEMB,IGOV,MINC,AGZD,FTSL,SPLV,GHYG,ISTB,ENGN,CMBS,GTIP,SCHO,SMMU,QLTA,SCHZ,HSPX,TUZ,GIY,GSY,TFLO,VMBS,CWB,FLOT,STPZ,MUAC,SCHR,BABZ,HYXU,GMTB,MUNI,WIP,MUAD,QLTB,SCHP,GMMB,MUAE,IPE,NYF,BNDX,MUAF,HYMB,TIPZ,CMF,LAG,ILTB,ITE,CLY,VGSH,VGIT,LTPZ,BABS,HYHG,EMCB,DVYL,VGLT,DHS,TLO,VWOB,IGHG,GLCB,RAVI,VCSH,BSV,BND,BIV,ISHG,SDYL,VCIT,SHY,BLV,HYG,VCLT,TENZ,DTN,BIL,AUD,DLN,DTD,FTSD,CAD,STIP,CORP,HYS,HOLD,TRSY,IEF,IBDA,COBO,BOND,MINT,MBB,CSJ,AGG,SUB,EMB,CIU,GVI,MUB,GBF,TIP,AGZ,CFT,LQD,TLT,IEI,TLH,DIA,BSJF,MONY&types=stats,quote&token=token_was_added_here');
  //https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/stock/market/batch?&types=price&symbols=aapl,fb,tsla&token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
  //https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/stock/market/batch?&types=quote&symbols=aapl,fb,tsla&token=
  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  //https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=CNPF,ICOL,PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD,IPFF,SMB,YDIV,YYY,PEY,PGF,SNLN,DVHL,AUNZ,MDIV,PHB,PFXF,FPE,TIPX,MLN,SDIV,SIPE,SEMF,EMAG,IEMF,EU,BSCM,LEMF,BSCL,BSCK,BSCJ,BSCI,DSUM,BSCF,KBWD,PCEF,BSCG,BSCH,HYEM,ITM,BKLN,PGHY,IBCE,PZT,IJNK,XMPT,THHY,QYLD,IHY,IYLD,SHYD,PRB,DVHI,GOVT,BSJJ,BSJK,RIGS,INY,IBCD,PZA,PFIG,IBCC,BSCE,PVI,MBG,CXA,FWDB,DIV,CHLC,BSJI,FLTR,PWZ,MUAH,IBDD,PICB,IBDB,BSJH,RVNU,BSJG,IBDC,XOVR,BSJE,EBND,PCY,BWX,SJNK,DES,ANGL,BAB,SST,EMCD,CBND,HYD,PLW,SCPB,FLRN,BWZ,KBWY,ELD,IBND,AOK,RWXL,ITR,DON,DGRS,JNK,TZD,EPU,PFF,HYLD,GGOV,ULST,SPHD,HFIN,DGRW,LWC,ALD,LEMB,AGND,ITIP,EMHY,QLTC,TFI,SRLN,HYLS,SHM,GNMA,CEMB,IGOV,MINC,AGZD,FTSL,SPLV,GHYG,ISTB,ENGN,CMBS,GTIP,SCHO,SMMU,QLTA,SCHZ,HSPX,TUZ,GIY,GSY,TFLO,VMBS,CWB,FLOT,STPZ,MUAC,SCHR,BABZ,HYXU,GMTB,MUNI,WIP,MUAD,QLTB,SCHP,GMMB,MUAE,IPE,NYF,BNDX,MUAF,HYMB,TIPZ,CMF,LAG,ILTB,ITE,CLY,VGSH,VGIT,LTPZ,BABS,HYHG,EMCB,DVYL,VGLT,DHS,TLO,VWOB,IGHG,GLCB,RAVI,VCSH,BSV,BND,BIV,ISHG,SDYL,VCIT,SHY,BLV,HYG,VCLT,TENZ,DTN,BIL,AUD,DLN,DTD,FTSD,CAD,STIP,CORP,HYS,HOLD,TRSY,IEF,IBDA,COBO,BOND,MINT,MBB,CSJ,AGG,SUB,EMB,CIU,GVI,MUB,GBF,TIP,AGZ,CFT,LQD,TLT,IEI,TLH,DIA,BSJF,MONY&types=quote,stats&token=
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  //final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String,dynamic>>();

  //return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();

  dynamic Obj = json.decode(responseBody);
  debugPrint(responseBody, wrapWidth: 8192);
  print(Obj.length);

  List<Photo> photoList = [];
  Obj.forEach((k, v) => photoList.add(Photo(k, v)));

  return photoList;
}

class Photo {
  String symbol;
  //String companyName;
  dynamic data;
  // dynamic iexClose;
  // dynamic quote;
  Photo(this.symbol, this.data);
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Monthly Paying ETFs';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('About'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                  'This app is to provide the list of ETF s that pay monthly dividend'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('for questions or feedback please contact me at  '),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
        future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Photo> photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos})
      : assert(photos != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _PhotosListState createState() => _PhotosListState();
}

class _PhotosListState extends State<PhotosList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return bodyData();
  }

  SingleChildScrollView bodyData() => SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        //padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        //  padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.001, .001, 1.0, 1.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.05),

        // child: FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.contain,

        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              child: DataTable(
                  // sortColumnIndex: 1,
                  //  sortAscending: true,

                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text("Company"),
                      onSort: (_, __) {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["quote"]
                                  ["companyName"]
                              .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["companyName"]));
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text("ttmDivRate"),
                      numeric: true,
                      onSort: (_, __) {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["quote"]
                                  ["ttmDividendRate"]
                              .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["ttmDividendRate"]));
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text("Price"),
                      numeric: true,
                      onSort: (_, __) {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["quote"]
                                  ["latestPrice"]
                              .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["latestPrice"]));
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                  rows: widget.photos
                      .map(
                        (photo) => DataRow(
                          cells: [
                            DataCell(
                              Text(
                                  '${photo.data["stats"]["companyName"] ?? ""}'),
                            ),

                            DataCell(
                              Text(
                                  '${photo.data["stats"]["ttmDividendRate"] ?? ""}'),
                            ),
//["quote"]["stats"]
                            DataCell(Text(
                                '${photo.data["stats"]["latestPrice"] ?? ""}')),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList())),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: The column Price is empty. 
If I try to call  **"delayedPrice":11.552,"** or **"iexClose":11.04.** it does not print in the app.

Comment: the problem seems to be with the methods you are trying to fetch the value, play with the structure for fetching the value. or try the link provide earlier for creating json model

Comment: I agree. ty for the insight. that's is the reason the question was raised.

Comment: crazy-lazy-cat any insight on this one?  The column Price is empty. If I try to call "delayedPrice":11.552," or "iexClose":11.04. it does not print in the app.